# Android->localhost->Java Spring

Tags: java, android, spring, localhost

Задача заключается в передаче логина и пароля(Android App) в ,поднятый на Java Spring, localhost,а затем уже забрать из самого Java. Сам я не местный, прошу дать направление поиска.
Код android:

```
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            URL url = new URL("10.0.2.2:8080/home.html");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(720000000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(72000000);
            OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.write(json);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            System.out.println(json);
            //  int HttpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
            connection.disconnect();
```

код java:

```
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/home.html");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();
```

Вероятно я что то не учёл, с android вообще встретился впервые, со стороны java опыта в таких вещах тоже не густо. Прошу помощи у сообщества) 
P.S: Буду искренне рад найти собеседника на данную тему.